# Spacing Issue for the Fields

Tags: python, pyspark

I am facing issue with Spacing. Total space in my txt file should be 1438 in one line ,the last field should end it here, but my last field is ending 1548 in the same line.

How to fix it till the space 1438 should be in same line. Then next line will start from space 1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you need to provide some sample data. we cant assume and prepare data. It could be as simple as replacing SPACE with NULL but unable to tell until you share the sample data